# Meaning of "deep pointlessness"

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the last line of [About Me page of Martin Fowlers'](http://martinfowler.com/aboutMe.html) website :

> I enjoy living in the US even though I miss the beer, the deep
>   pointlessness of Cricket, and the English countryside.

If he feels that the [game of cricket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket) is [pointless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pointless) why would he say that he is missing it or am I missing something here ?

Comment: This question is not about the English language. Maybe it's about the personality of Martin Fowler. In any case, off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's meant to be a quaint remark, given tongue-in-cheek.

In one sense, any sporting match is "pointless." It's just a game between two teams.  We can root for one side or the other, but who wins the match doesn't really have any real effect on society.

Moreover, cricket matches are known for lasting a very long time.

So, *deep pointlessness* is an oxymoron of sorts. He's saying that games can last a profoundly long time, and be almost addicting to watch, even though the final outcome won't really matter in the long run.

Still, it was fun for him to do, so, he misses it, living in the U.S., where it would be very difficult for him to find a good cricket match (and a good English beer, too, apparently).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that something is pointless does not mean you have to dislike it.

Besides, he may be missing the opportunity to complain about how pointless Cricket is.